# C# method binding

Tags: c#, .net

[Dotnet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#binding-extension-methods-at-compile-time) state that:

> An extension method with the same name and signature as an interface
> or class method will never be called. At compile time, extension
> methods always have lower priority than instance methods defined in
> the type itself. In other words, if a type has a method named
> Process(int i), and you have an extension method with the same
> signature, the compiler will always bind to the instance method. When
> the compiler encounters a method invocation, it first looks for a
> match in the type's instance methods. If no match is found, it will
> search for any extension methods that are defined for the type, and
> bind to the first extension method that it finds.

So the expectation is that `test.AnotherTestMethod()` and `test.TestMethodWithArgs("main")` should be called from the instance in the following example:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ITest test = new TestClass();
        
        test.TestMethod();
        
        test.AnotherTestMethod();
        
        test.TestMethodWithArgs("main");
    }
}

public interface ITest 
{
    void TestMethod();
}

public class TestClass : ITest
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("[TestMethod()] Instance method");
    }
    
    public void AnotherTestMethod()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("[AnotherTestMethod()] Instance method");
    }
    
    public void TestMethodWithArgs(string S)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("[TestMethodWithArgs(string S)] Instance method: " + S);
    }
}

public static class TestExtensions
{
    public static void AnotherTestMethod(this ITest target)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("[AnotherTestMethod()] Extension method");
    }
    
    public static void TestMethodWithArgs(this ITest target, string S)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("[TestMethodWithArgs(string S)] Extension method: " + S);
    }
}
```

However, this is what I'm ending up with for with `.NET 4.7.2` and `.NET 6`:

```
[TestMethod()] Instance method
[AnotherTestMethod()] Extension method
[TestMethodWithArgs(string S)] Extension method: main
```

Why is the binding not consistent with the documentation? Is there anything wrong in the sample code?

Comment: You are calling methods on `ITest`, not `TestClass`. The binding spoken of is compile-time, not runtime. Change the declared type of `test` to `TestClass` and you'll see the expected behavior.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Changing the declared types works. However my use case is a little more complicated than this example. I'm trying to write an adapter for [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#extension-methods) that wraps another logger type and uses it to log when its APIs are invoked. The reason for it is I need to pass a logger to library code that expects the extensions logging type but where I'm using it the logger interface is a different type

Comment: For that purpose you need to ignore all the extension methods and focus only on the methods implemented by `ILogger`, since ultimately all the extension methods boil down to some invocation of those. This may be far more complicated and less convenient than tweaking an extension method's implementation, but unfortunately that's not possible.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with `ILogger`, but in the example you showed, changing it to `dynamic` should also work.

Comment: XY problem... your basic approach of writing an adapter sounds reasonable, but (since you ended up writing this question) you took a wrong turn somewhere. Since the usage of your logger is within some library, even `dynamic` can't save you - compile time binding is already done by the time you use the library. There is no reasonable way (lets ignore the possibility to fork the library source or to tweak the library assembly) to change the fact that your library is calling some extension methods. As JeroenMostert said, focus on the actual members of the interface.